# Stop form submission on photo uploading (userpro plugin)

Tags: wordpress

I am using user-pro plugin and in my registration page having field like below..

(1) Profile-picture 
(2) First name (field required validation) 
(3) Last name (field required validation) 
(4) Country....etc

problem is their when I upload image and click on submit button then it fire the validation to other field and show the error message whey it happens.

so how can I stop the validation which is fire automatically..?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It fire just because of below code which I found in script.min.js file. below code fire trigger any input.

```
    form.find('input').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).trigger('blur');
    });
```

just remove above code from that file and problem is solved.